# Middle-button scroll not working in Ubuntu 12.04 [Thinkpad X230]

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, trackpad

My track-point works, so does my track pad. The middle button of both my trackpad and my mouse can be used to close applications among other things. But I just cannot use it to scroll (the way we do in Windows).
I have tried almost everything listed out here : [How To Configure The TrackPoint - ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint)

I've attached the outputs of a couple of commands here :

```
root@vishnu-pc:~# xinput list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
unable to find device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
```

And,

```
root@vishnu-pc:~# xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I cannot find my touchpad/trackpad listed anywhere here. I've already installed `GPointingDeviceSettings` and that hasn't helped either. I've also tried disabling the trackpad from BIOS to see if that would make a difference, but to no avail.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a known [Bug #1130471](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1130471), that is fixed upstream, what means, you can hope for the fix to be there on 14.04 LTS or you can try to find the patch and apply it for yourself. Kernelbuildtime, baby... ;)

Comment: @mondjunge : I'm using 3.5.0-40, while according to the link you posted, the issue was resolved in 3.5.0-25 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1130471/comments/8)

Comment: very odd. Since I do not find similar problems and the x230 Trackpad is mentioned to be working "out-of-the-box", I presume you did a configuration error somewhere or nobody noticed the revision of the bug. I am sorry that I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Error message you got seems clearly telling you what's wrong no?; you don't have `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` on your machine. What if replacing it with `ThinkPad Extra Buttons` that's printed in your `xinput` output?

Atually I've got my middle-button working by following the link you provided. In my case:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Trackball                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ThinkPad Keyboard                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ BisonCam, NB Pro                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
$ xinput set-prop "ThinkPad Keyboard" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
$ xinput set-prop "ThinkPad Keyboard" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
$ xinput set-prop "ThinkPad Keyboard" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
```