# How can scrolling when the middle clickpad button is pressed be enabled?

Tags: touchpad, mouse-scroll, scrolling

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga which is equipped with a clickpad. I want to enable scrolling using the middle clickpad button. So, I want to be able to scroll in, say, an editor by pressing and holding the middle button and then moving the mouse in the direction in which to scroll. I have set up this clickpad such that the three soft buttons corresponding to mouse buttons 1, 2 and 3 are recognised. The synaptics configuration is as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
    MatchDriver "synaptics"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "64% 0 1 42% 36% 64% 1 42%"
    Option "AreaBottomEdge" "1"
EndSection
```

The xinput device listing (xinput --list) is as follows:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The xinput properties listing for the pointing stick device (xinput --list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint") is as follows:

```
Device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (134):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (262): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (251):    2, 10
    Device Node (252):  "/dev/input/event15"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (266): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (268):  0
    Axis Labels (269):  "Rel X" (144), "Rel Y" (145)
    Button Labels (270):    "Button Left" (137), "Button Middle" (138), "Button Right" (139), "Button Wheel Up" (140), "Button Wheel Down" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (142), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (143)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (271):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (272):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (273): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (274): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (275):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (276):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (277):    1
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (278):   6, 7, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (279):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (280):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (281): 2
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (282):  0
```

The xinput properties listing for the clickpad device (xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad") is as follows:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (134):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (262): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (308):  1768, 5414, 1638, 4466
    Synaptics Finger (309): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (310):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (311):   235
    Synaptics Tap Durations (312):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (313):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (314):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (315):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (316):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (317): 107, 107
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (318): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (319):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (320): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.037293, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (321):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (322):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (323):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (324): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (325):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (326): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (327):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (328): 0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (329): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (330):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (331): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (332):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (333): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (334):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (335):  1
    Synaptics Gestures (336):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (337):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (338): 55, 53
    Synaptics Area (339):   0, 0, 0, 1
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (340):  4184, 0, 1, 2788, 2997, 4184, 1, 2788
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (341): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (251):    2, 7
    Device Node (252):  "/dev/input/event10"
```

Sample `xev` output for the button usage is as follows:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 17803214, (103,77), root:(1845,126),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 17803294, (103,77), root:(1845,126),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

I would appreciate any guidance you might have on enabling the middle button scrolling. Thanks!

EDIT: I've acquired an external ThinkPad USB keyboard that features both a TrackPoint pointing stick and three dedicated mouse buttons. I have performed the scroll up and scroll down operations successfully using this keyboard and have recorded the relevant `xev` output.

The following is the `xev` output for the successful scroll up operation:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x4c00002, time 53834970, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 53834946, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 4096

KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967198 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ButtonRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x4c00002, time 53834970, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 53834946, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
```

The following is the `xev` output for the successful scroll down operation:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x4c00002, time 53829778, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 53829754, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 4096

KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967198 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ButtonRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x4c00002, time 53829778, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x9e, subw 0x0, time 53829754, (55,63), root:(1797,1083),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
```

So, with this additional information, would any of you kind, clever people have any guidance on how to instate this type of scrolling on my little ThinkPad? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xinput` setting like the link mentioned [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360167/middle-button-scroll-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04-thinkpad-x230)? The recognized device `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` is exactly what's explained there.